# Selective serialization of Java Object

Tags: java

Consider a case where I've 10 fields in my Java class. What I want is, do some special handling for few of them (say 3) and rest of the fields been serialized via default `ObjectOutputStream` implementation. Is there a way to achieve this?

I can provide the implementation of `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os)` in my class to specially handle these 3 fields, but how to default for rest of fields?

Comment: Sure!  Try implementing the `Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException` method, and set the defaults in there.  See [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html) for precise details on how this works with `ObjectInputStream`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

- declare the three special fields as transient
- implement `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)` and in this method:
- use `ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject()` to write all other fields in the default way
- then add your custom serialization for the special fields

and add analog implementations to read the object.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable
{
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        // add code to write the special fields
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException
    {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        // add code to read the special fields
    }

    private transient int special1;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason the three "special" fields should be declared as `transient`? IIUC transient means "should not be serialized" in JAVA.

Comment: @TT as transient fields they will be ignored by `ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject()` and `ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject()`